# Конфигурирование GitLab CI

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Доброго времени суток.

Я разрабатываю приложения на C# .Net 4.0 в качестве системы контроля версий использую gitlab 8.8.5, которую установил на Ubuntu. Теперь появилась необходимость в CI. Установил все необходимое для этого gitlab-ci-multi-runner. Для проекта создал раннер. Добавил в корень мастер ветки файлик .gitlab-ci.yml, при пуше запускается build все нормально. Не могу правильно сконфигурировать **.gitlab-ci.yml**(что туда необходимо добавить) для построения моего проекта и деплой на другой сервер. Сервер не имеет подключения к интернету.

Comment: Покажите, что у вас там сейчас в этом файле? (только удалите всякие логины-пароли)

Comment: Что вы сейчас используете для деплоя? Вручную ставите, через систему управления конфигами, через контейнеры вроде докера?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Сейчас в этом файле ничего нету. Я просто взял пример и попробовал, что работает.  Я делаю такое впервые. Ставил докеры. Подскажите может быть есть способ попроще.

Comment: пример конфига http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#examples

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы понять, что есть что в `.gitlab-ci.yml`, лучше начать с совсем простых [конфигов из GitLab Pages](https://gitlab.com/groups/pages)

Вот например конфиг для lektor:

```
image: python:2.7
pages:
  script:
  - pip install lektor
  - lektor build --output-path public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

- **image** - это образ докера, который вы берете за основу.
- **pages** - это просто название этапа. У вас может быть build, test или deploy, или еще что-то.
- То что должно запускаться, вы записываете в **script**. Просто команды одну за одной как если бы вы запускали их из командной строки.
- **artifacts** - это откуда брать бинарники(или что там у вас генерится в процессе билда), чтобы положить это в секцию Artifacts каждого билда
- C помощью **only** и **except** можно гибко наруливать так, чтобы этап выполнялся для пуша только в эту ветку, или, соответственно, для пуша во все ветки кроме указанной
- Если у вас есть какие-то секретные ключи, то не нужно их класть в `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Для этого есть секция Variables в настройках вашего проекта.

Чтобы у вас сначала билдилось, потом деплоилось, нужно задать `stages`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
```

Если `stages` не задать, то этапы будут выполняться параллельно, т.е. деплоиться будет не зависимо от того, сбилдилось ли.

@marsel-arduanov в общем правильную ссылку вам скинул, но там много всего, и сходу не разберешься куда бежать.

В итоге ваш конфиг может выглядеть как-то так, например:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
build:
  script:
  - <your command 1 to build>
  - <your command 2 to build>
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - build
deploy:
  script:
  - <your command to deploy>
  only:
  - master
```

Для ситуации когда нет интернета, можно использовать встроенный [Container Registry](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/container_registry.html), чтобы брать образа из него.